# Use ML.NET trained model in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, .net

How would i use a ML.NET trained (with VS ML Model Builder) model in Python?

It's a .zip file btw.

ZIP file structure:

```
MLModel1.zip
│   Schema
│
├───TrainingInfo
│       Version.txt
│
└───TransformerChain
    │   Model.key
    │
    ├───Transform_000
    │   │   Model.key
    │   │
    │   └───Vocabulary
    │           Model.key
    │           Terms.txt
    │
    ├───Transform_001
    │   │   Model.key
    │   │   TrainSchema
    │   │
    │   └───Model
    │           Model.key
    │           TFModel
    │
    └───Transform_002
            Model.key
```